# how can I transform my chaincode from local to peer in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

If I write a piece of Hyperledger Fabric chaincode in go on local, how can I transform my chaincode from local to fabric peer ?

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail of what you've tried. Suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To rwp's point, here's an example:
I've followed the guide on developing chaincode in developer mode.  I now want to deploy this to a network of peers.  I tried .... | I could not find an example ... | ...

Comment: When you say "how can I transform my chaincode", do you mean how to install and instantiate the chaincode on a peer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that, when you say "how can I transform my chaincode from local to peer", you mean that you want to install and instantiate the chaincode on a peer. 
You can follow the steps provided [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#install-instantiate-chaincode). 
If you're following the tutorial provided [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#building-your-first-network), I'd suggest you create the artifacts manually and follow the steps from [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#manually-generate-the-artifacts). 
Specifically, using cli, you install a chaincode into a peer from the cli container using the following command :

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p path/to/your/chaincode/
```

The argument to the `-p` option specifies the path to the chaincode, which must be located within the source tree of the user’s `GOPATH`

Comment: thanks your answer, but you did not ansewer my question. I konw how to install chaincode. When I install chaincode, there are condition, my chaincode code file has been transfered on peer. But how can I do it ?

Comment: -p option can't through the contain to access my local file system.